# Appending Xpath Value to List Using For Loop in Scrapy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scrapy

I'm looking to try and automate my html table scrape in Scrapy. This is what I have so far:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd

class XGSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'expectedGoals'

    start_urls = [
        'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/schedule/Premier-League-Scores-and-Fixtures',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        matches = []

        for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="sched_ks_3232_1"]//tbody/tr'):

            match = {
                'home': row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract_first(),
                'homeXg': row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract_first(),
                'score': row.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract_first(),
                'awayXg': row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract_first(),
                'away': row.xpath('td[8]//text()').extract_first()
            }

            matches.append(match)

        x = pd.DataFrame(
            matches, columns=['home', 'homeXg', 'score', 'awayXg', 'away'])

        yield x.to_csv("xG.csv", sep=",", index=False)
```

It works fine, however as you can see I am hardcoding the keys (`home`, `homeXg`, etc.) for the `match` object. I'd like to automate scraping the keys to a list and then initialize a dict wih keys from said list. Problem is, I don't know how to loop through xpath by index. As an example,

```
 headers = [] 
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="sched_ks_3260_1"]/thead/tr'): 
            yield{
                'first': row.xpath('th[1]/text()').extract_first(),
                'second': row.xpath('th[2]/text()').extract_first()
            }
```

Is it possible to stick `th[1]`, `th[2]`, `th[3]` etc. into a for loop, with the numbers as indexes, and appending the values to a list? e.g.

`row.xpath('th[i]/text()').extract_first()` ?

Comment: Not sure I understood the question. Wouldn't a f string solve your issue? Like: `row.xpath(f'th[{index_var}]/text()')` ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new with Python, maybe the question wasn't clear... The header keys are hardcoded at the moment, I'd like to automate its scraping, but to do so I'd have to figure out how to count the amount of columns there are in the table, and then loop through each xpath- not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but should work:

```
column_index = 1
columns = {}
for column_node in response.xpath('//*[@id="sched_ks_3260_1"]/thead/tr/th'):
    column_name = column_node.xpath('./text()').extract_first()
    columns[column_name] = column_index
    column_index += 1
    matches = []

for row in response.xpath('//*[@id="sched_ks_3232_1"]//tbody/tr'):
    match = {}        
    for column_name in columns.keys():
        match[column_name] = row.xpath('./td[{index}]//text()'.format(index=columns[column_name])).extract_first()
    matches.append(match)
```